# Ansible pops up with an error "PyVmomi Python module required."

Tags: ansible, vmware

I have a playbook to create a vm in vmware environment with ansible, but it always pops up with an error **PyVmomi Python module required. Install using \"pip install PyVmomi**, even though I have already installed it.
Can someone help me resolve this

[Environment]

```
[root@ansible]# ansible --version
ansible 2.7.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Apr 11 2018, 07:36:10) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)]

[root@ansible]# pip show pyvmomi
Name: pyvmomi
Version: 6.7.0.2018.9
Summary: VMware vSphere Python SDK
Home-page: https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi
Author: VMware, Inc.
Author-email: jhu@vmware.com
License: License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: requests, six
Required-by:


[PlayBook]
[root@ansible]# cat vmware.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Clone the template
    vmware_guest:
      hostname: **.**.**.**
      username: root
      password: *****
      validate_certs: False
      name: ansible-vm
      template: template-gold
      datacenter: DC1
      folder: /DC1/vm
      state: poweredon
      wait_for_ip_address: yes
```

I am editing my question and posting the asked results..
Edited host file with below details

[my_ws]
localhost ansible_python_interpreter={{ansible_playbook_python}}

Error..
[root@ansible]# ansible-playbook test1.yml

PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [command] ******************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["/usr/bin/python2", "-c", "import pyvmomi; print(pyvmomi.**version**)"], "delta": "0:00:00.090749", "end": "2018-10-10 11:12:22.345576", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2018-10-10 11:12:22.254827", "stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"\", line 1, in \nImportError: No module named pyvmomi", "stderr_lines": ["Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File \"\", line 1, in ", "ImportError: No module named pyvmomi"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
        to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/test1.retry

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

Comment: @techraf I have already gone through that Question but it has not resolve my problem, hence I opened a new one.

Comment: Can someone please help me with this, I am new to ansible and need to resolve this problem

Comment: The answer under the dup-target contains a method to verify the existence of the package. I can't see the result of that check in your question, so maybe you "have already gone", but you keep it to yourself. How do you expect someone to help you, if you don't share the information?

Comment: Cannot say for sure, but there might be conflicting versions. Try creating a virtual environment and install ansible and pyvmomi in that.